# nav drawer checked wrong after intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

[image]

PatientReport.java

```
public class PatientReport extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
int navItemId;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private EditText inputEmail, inputTitle, inputMessage;
private TextView level;
private TextInputLayout inputLayoutEmail, inputLayoutTitle, inputLayoutMessage;
private Button btnSend;
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayAdapter<String> lunchList;
private Context mContext;
private static final String NAV_ITEM_ID = "nav_index";

private String[] em_level = {"Low", "Medium", "High"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.patient_report);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("E-care");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Toast.makeText(PatientReport.this, menuItem.getItemId() + " pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(R.id.nav_1 + "", menuItem.getItemId() + " ");
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                case R.id.nav_1:

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_2:

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_3:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_4:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_5:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_6:
                    break;

            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open , R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super .onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super .onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    level= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);

    inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
    inputLayoutTitle = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_title);
    inputLayoutMessage = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_message);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    inputTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_title);
    inputMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_message);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
    lunchList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PatientReport.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, em_level);
    spinner.setAdapter(lunchList);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            // Toast.makeText(mContext, "你選的是" + em_level[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

    inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));
    inputTitle.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputTitle));
    inputMessage.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputMessage));

    level.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            submitForm();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_case_history_review, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void navigateTo(MenuItem menuItem){

    navItemId = menuItem.getItemId();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(NAV_ITEM_ID, 2);
}
/**
 * If the form is valid, the button will immediately intent to the email client
 */
private void submitForm() {
    if (!validateEmail()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!validateTitle()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!validateMessage()) {
        return;
    }

    String to = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    String title = inputTitle.getText().toString();
    String message = "Emergency Level: " + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n" + "Detail : " + inputMessage.getText().toString();

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
    //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
    //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    //need this to prompts email client only
    email.setType("message/rfc822");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
}

private boolean validateEmail() {

    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
        inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
        requestFocus(inputEmail);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        inputEmail.setLinkTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean validateTitle() {
    if (inputTitle.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutTitle.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_title));
        requestFocus(inputTitle);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutTitle.setErrorEnabled(false);
        inputTitle.setLinkTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean validateMessage() {
    if (inputMessage.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutMessage.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_message));
        requestFocus(inputMessage);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutMessage.setErrorEnabled(false);
        inputMessage.setLinkTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    return true;
}

private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}

private void requestFocus(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.input_email:
                validateEmail();
                break;
            case R.id.input_title:
                validateTitle();
                break;
            case R.id.input_message:
                validateMessage();
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

case_history_review.java

```
public class Case_history_review extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private TextView contentView;
private int navItemId;

private static final String NAV_ITEM_ID = "nav_index";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_case_history_review);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("E-care");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Toast.makeText(Case_history_review.this, menuItem.getItemId() + " pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(R.id.nav_1+"", menuItem.getItemId() + " ");
            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_1:

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_2:
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(Case_history_review.this,PatientReport.class);
                    //intent .putExtra("name", "Hello B Activity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_3:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_4:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_5:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_6:
                    break;

            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open , R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super .onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super .onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_case_history_review, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void navigateTo(MenuItem menuItem){

    navItemId = menuItem.getItemId();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //outState.putInt(NAV_ITEM_ID, navItemId);
}




 }
```

This is my second page so I want to show the checked nav in the second row. 
Case_history_review.java intents to the  patient_report.java 
However, after clicking the button and intending to this page, the nav drawer checked in the first row and I cannot solve it.Please give me some helps. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two activities to show their independent `NavigationDrawer` . Ideally you show show `Fragment` for each `NavigationItem` in your `Drawer`. So in your case, you are recreating the `Drawer` each time moving to new `Activity`.

In your `onCreate` in the `PatientReport.java` add this line,

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
```

after creating `NavigationView`.

Comment: Oops.Thank you. Is there any other way to use the created navigation instead of create a new one in another activity?

Comment: Yes as I said you should be using Fragments to navigate from Drawer. Because you cannot use views sharing between activities. Activity is an independent component. You can refer android docs to see how to implement NavigtationDrawer for Fragments. Hope it helps.